# Differences among iOS Simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have an app that is intensive computationally but is fairly simple programatically. For example, there are no threads. Everything is straight-line.

If I run the app in the iPhone retina 3.5" simulator, I can get exercise the app enough to get it to cause an access violation without much difficulty:

{Called from the UIView drawRect method}

```
UIImage *image = [self getImage] ;
[image drawAtPoint:point] ; // Crash here-no identifiable pattern when it crashes here.
```

The `getImage` method either returns a pointer to a `UIImage` already loaded or loads the image and returns the pointer. The debugger appears to show a valid `UIImage` after a crash.

If I run the app in any of the other simulators, do not encounter a problem. In fact, this is the first access violation I have seen since developing this app.

Is there something that is inherently different with the 3.5" simulator or phone?

Comment: The phones are slower, but the sim probably isn't.  You'd probably be better off figuring out why it's crashing. What exactly is the crash and stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was. Sort of.

I noticed that it was always crashing on the same same image. I have 1700 images, whenever it was displaying this one in the 3-1/2" simulator---crash.

I loaded the PNG image into photoshop (where it had been created originally). I changed from Indexed color to RGB and no more crash.

I have no idea why it only crashed on that one simulator. Preview, Safari, Chrome and Photoshop had no problem with the image.